# Using array in class

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble using array with class
My .h file:

```
#ifndef SUDOKU_H
#define SUDOKU_H

class sudoku {
public:
    sudoku();
    bool findUnassignedLocation(int, int, int);
    bool isSafe(int, int, int);
    bool usedInRow(int, int, int);
    bool usedInCol(int, int, int);
    bool usedInBox(int, int, int, int);
    void printGrid(int);
    void solveSudoku(int);
private:
    static const int N;
    static const int UNASSIGNED;
};

#endif  /* SUDOKU_H */
```

My .cpp file:

```
#include "sudoku.h"

sudoku::sudoku() {
    N = 9;
    UNASSIGNED = 0;
}

bool sudoku::findUnassignedLocation(int grid[N][N], int &row, int &col){
    for (row = 0; row < N; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < N; col++)
            if (grid[row][col] == UNASSIGNED)
                return true;
        return false;
}

bool sudoku::usedInRow(int grid[N][N], int row, int num){
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
            return true;
    return false;
}

bool sudoku::usedInCol(int grid[N][N], int col, int num){
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
            return true;
    return false;
}

bool sudoku::usedInBox(int grid[N][N], int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num){
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            if (grid[row+boxStartRow][col+boxStartCol] == num)
                return true;
    return false;
}

bool sudoku::isSafe(int grid[N][N], int row, int col, int num){
    return !usedInBox(grid, row - row % 3 , col - col % 3, num) &&
           !usedInCol(grid, col, num) && !usedInRow(grid, row, num); 
}

void sudoku::solveSudoku(int grid[N][N]){
    int row, col;
    if(!findUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col)){
        printGrid(grid);
    }

    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++){
        if(isSafe(grid, row, col, num)){
            grid[row][col] = num;
            if(solveSudoku(grid))
                printGrid(grid);
            grid[row][col] = UNASSIGNED;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "No Solution" << std::endl;
}

void sudoku::printGrid(int grid[N][N]){
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
             std::cout<<grid[row][col]<<"  ";
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

And my main file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "sudoku.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    sudoku S;
    int grid[9][9] = {{3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0},
                      {5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1},
                      {0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0},
                      {9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5},
                      {0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0},
                      {1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4},
                      {0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0}};

    S.solveSudoku(grid);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why my output show this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:28:23: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[9]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
     S.solveSudoku(grid);
In file included from main.cpp:8:0:
sudoku.h:20:10: note: initializing argument 1 of 'void sudoku::solveSudoku(int)'
     void solveSudoku(int);
```

I believe the problem is with pointers, but I'm starting in C++ so I can't find the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Your function definitions differ from your declarations.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: It's best to name parameters even in the class definition to help people understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

The member function declared like

```
void solveSudoku(int);
```

that is it has one parameter of type `int`.

You call this function

```
S.solveSudoku(grid);
```

passing to it a two-dimensional array

```
int grid[9][9]
```

The compiler is unable to convert pointer to the first element of the array that has type `int ( * )[9]` to an object of type `int`.

It seems there is a typo because after the member function declaration you defined it like

```
void sudoku::solveSudoku(int grid[N][N]){
//...
```

So update the function declaration in the class definition.

Also this constructor

```
sudoku::sudoku() {
    N = 9;
    UNASSIGNED = 0;
}
```

is invalid because N and UNASSIGNED are declared as constant static members

```
static const int N;
static const int UNASSIGNED;
```

Comment: Yes, I got it. But I don't know the correct way to declare my member function

Comment: @user2792523 Declare it in the class definition the same way as you declared it in its own definition

Comment: My own definition is int grid[N][N]. I can't declare it on my class definition. Right?

Comment: @user2792523 Replace  declaration  void solveSudoku(int); in the class definition with void sudoku::solveSudoku(int grid[N][N]);

Comment: @user2792523  In my preceding post there is clear written how the function should be defined.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. you sait to use this sudoku::solveSudoku(int grid[N][N]) in class definition??

Comment: @user2792523  There was a typo. Simply replace record  void solveSudoku(int);  with record  void solveSudoku(int grid[N][N]); in the class definition.

Comment: solveSudoku(int grid[N][N]) in class definition will generate the error: 'N' was not declared in this scope

Comment: If I declare like that void solveSudoku(int [][9]), it's work. But I would like to use a variable in place of the number 9

Comment: @user2792523  Declare static data member static const int N; like  static const int N = 9; Also see my updated post.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. But I can't declare void solveSudoku(int [N][N]). "Unable to resolve identifier N"

Comment: @user2792523 You have to place this constant declaration before the function declaration in the class definition.

Comment: I put before, but still same problem

Comment: @user2792523 In a .cpp module write const int sudoku::N;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got it. But I don't know the correct way to declare my member function